# Finite Automata Library written in F#

Tags: f#, dfa, nfa

Could you recommend an open source library written in F# which provides generic types for FA construction and basic algorithms (NFA to DFA transformation, FA minimization ...)?

Comment: This is something I could use too.  If one doesn't exist, I sure wish somebody would write one!

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be to use the state machine monad, which has be blogged/written/discussed/produced several times, a couple of references are below.

http://fsharpcode.blogspot.com/2008/12/f-state-monad-type-state-state-state-of.html
http://codebetter.com/blogs/matthew.podwysocki/archive/2009/12/30/much-ado-about-monads-state-edition.aspx

although this doesn't give you the translations you want...
Might be a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you are looking for but a quick and dirty way to get some FA things working would be to write an equivalent context free grammar for your FA then using [fsyacc](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

[Jolt.NET](http://jolt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Jolt.FSM&referringTitle=Jolt.Automata)

It does not fulfil all your requirements: It's in C#, and it does not seem to support translation to DFA or minimization. At least it's usable from F# and could be used as a starting point. I've never used it myself, so I can't vouch for its suitability or quality.

See also [NFA/DFA implementation in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006234/nfa-dfa-implementation-in-c)