# NFA/DFA implementation in C#

Tags: c#, automata, dfa, nfa

Does anyone know of any good NFA and DFA implementation in C#, possibly implementing as well conversions between both? What I would like would be to be able to construct a NFA and then convert it automatically to a DFA, but without having to write my own code which would take a very long time. There is [this](http://gist.github.com/491973) Python code which perhaps I could use and integrate with C# using IronPython, but Python is slow.

Comment: Looking that the python code, it should be relatively easy to convert to C#.  Have you considered doing that?

Comment: The question is that I understand nothing about Python...

Comment: Slow is relative... anyway, the NFA->DFA algorithm is rather trivial (with some general caveats in general) and is a topic of many Junior CS Automata-Theory courses -- I had to do this :) There any many good links off of "convert NFA to DFA" on google. Look at those relating to courses in particular. It should be less than a day of coding; perhaps only a few an hour or two and likely less painful than trying to hopscotch through different languages.

Comment: The algorithm to convert NFAs to DFAs is exponential in the number of NFA states in the worst case, so... slow is not going to be a phenomenon due to Python.

Comment: You may also want to look at project Fare. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841454/convert-nfa-to-dfa/8240209#8240209

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Take a look at my series of posts about this subject:

[Regular Expression Engine in C# (the Story)](http://www.leniel.net/2009/02/regular-expression-engine-in-csharp.html)

[Regex engine in C# - the Regex Parser](http://www.leniel.net/2009/02/regex-engine-in-csharp-regexparser.html)

[Regex engine in C# - the NFA](http://www.leniel.net/2009/04/regex-engine-in-csharp-nfa.html)

[Regex engine in C# - the DFA](http://www.leniel.net/2009/05/regex-engine-in-csharp-dfa.html)

[Regex engine in C# - matching strings](http://www.leniel.net/2009/05/regex-engine-in-csharp-match-strings.html)

Comment: I would like to use your code, but it does not have a license listed. If you are ok with people using it, would you distribute a version with an explicit license?

Comment: @FireLizzard you can use it the way you want. In my blog I have included a Creative Commons badge right below my G+ profile. :) Feel free to use the code.