# convert nfa to dfa

Tags: c#, graph, draw, dfa, nfa

i want to write a program that convert nfa to dfa , 
user draw a graph then Program convert it to dfa .
how can i do it?

Comment: Do you know how to do it by hand?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at this previous question for incites.

[NFA/DFA implementation in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006234/nfa-dfa-implementation-in-c)

as indicated in the answer you could approach the problem by re-implementing the following python example in C#

https://gist.github.com/491973

If you are not bothered about the implementation language and simply wish to play with NFA's and DFA's then you can use:

http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/jflap/

here is a tutorial for doing just that:

http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/jflap/tutorial/fa/nfa2dfa/index.html

Comment: aha , thx for introducing jflap . just i want to have program like jflap using c#

Comment: Does it need to be in c#? If your concerned that you want it to run on the .Net VM you can simply make use of http://www.ikvm.net/ and it should run fine, no need for a JVM in sight!

Comment: aha . i dont know java . c# have no ablilty to write a program like jflap !

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at [Fare](https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare).

It is a .NET port of the well established Java library **dk.brics.automaton** with API as close as possible to the corresponding dk.brics.automaton classes.

It even includes a .NET port of **Xeger**, for generating random text from regular expressions.